# Вопрос по file_get_contents()

Tags: php

Есть страница, которая показывает `echo file_get_contents('url')`, можно ли узнать этот url?

Comment: открыть исходник этой страницы в редакторе и посмотреть

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете что на каком то сайте используется запрос на получение документа с другого сайта серверными методами, и у вас нет ни доступа ни возможности перехвата сигнала, то думаю что у вас нет возможности с точностью сказать куда идет запрос.

Может быть в теле документа есть какой то намек? посмотрите где лежат статические файлы (картинки, js, css)